# Azure blob storage error: Multiple condition headers are not supported

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

For a project I'm using Azure blob storage to store uploaded image files. I'm also displaying the uploaded images on the website - however, that's where things go wrong. Every other request to an image in blobstorage results in a `400 - Multiple condition headers not supported`.

Reading up on this error eventually leads me to the following documentation about specifying conditional request headers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179371.aspx

That page says the following about specifying multiple conditional headers:

> If a request specifies both the If-None-Match and If-Modified-Since headers, the request is evaluated based on the criteria specified in If-None-Match.
>
> If a request specifies both the If-Match and If-Unmodified-Since headers, the request is evaluated based on the criteria specified in If-Match.
>
> With the exception of the two combinations of conditional headers listed above, a request may specify only a single conditional header. Specifying more than one conditional header results in status code 400 (Bad Request).

I believe the requests sent by chrome meet all the requirements outlined by this documentation, and yet I receive that error.

Does anyone have experience with Azure blob storage that might help overcome this issue? I'd be most grateful!

The request as sent by Chrome:

[image: The request as sent by chrome]

The XML response as returned by the blob storage service:

[image: The XML response from the blob storage service]

Comment: Could there be a proxy/cache server between you and Azure that is adding it's own conditional headers?  What happens when you do the same test from a different network (ie. from an Azure VM)?

Comment: Also, can you tell us how big are the files stored in blob storage?

Comment: The files are max. 2mb in size, just normal image upload really. The proxy/cache server was an interesting suggestion. I tested it from an Azure VM and was not able to reproduce the error, so I assume the shared office space that I'm in must add its own cache headers.

That adds a bit of a problem of its own however, the website we're working on is supposed to be used by employees in medium to big companies - the type of companies that might also employ proxy/cache servers for their office WiFi. Is there something we could do to work around this? (short of routing requests through our webrole)

Comment: have you tried using https?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is because of cache, at least it was because of cache for me. I am using SAS so my solution was to add a extra parameter to avoid caching.

```
/// token = SharedAccessSignature
    string tick = $"&{ DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Ticks}";
    Uri url = new Uri(file.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + token + tick);
```

The extra parameter should be ignored by the web application.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who receive the similar error :

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Error> <Code>UnsupportedHeader</Code> <Message>One of the HTTP headers specified in the request is not supported.RequestId:1d567c06-501e-003e-297a-cf68e8000000Time:2023-08-15T13:17:57.5988095Z </Message> <HeaderName>Transfer-Encoding</HeaderName> </Error>`

even though the "Transfer-Encoding" header is not added anywhere, just add the header "Content-Length: <calculated_content_length>"

```
$headers['Content-Length'] = strlen($data);
```

This fixed it for me.